# Function to get Value of formula in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I know that it's possible to get the value of a formula in excel by selecting the cell, pressing F2 and then F9. This also destroys the formula. I need to be able to do this automatically, to a different cell so that I can keep the value. I'm currently using the    `=view|tagname!` to pull information from a local system. So every time the workbook is calculated the value changes and I need to be able to capture past values.

I tried:

```
Function Absolute(ByVal X As Range) As Double
     Absolute = X.Vlaue
End Function
```

This gives me the value of the cell but it changes every time the sheet is calculated.

Have also tried something along this route:

```
Function Absolute(X as Double)
   Absolute = Application.Calculate(X)
End Function
```

Comment: You will need to use vba in a Worksheet_Calculate event.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me service.  Try to do it and when you get stuck bring our code back here and tell us what it is doing that is incorrect or in error.

Comment: Excel already has a Absolute function ABS()

Comment: I know but it does the same thing, upon recalculation changes the value. I appreciate the help I think you were right about the worksheet_Calculate event needing to be changed so that it doesn't happen every time.

Answer (score 0):

As Scott points out, try something, then come back if you need help ironing it out.

Hint: Forget the whole "absolute" thing .. no idea what you're trying to do there ..

the functionality you want is called "copy" ...

you can record a macro ... do something (ie copy) .. look at the macro, and then tweak it to be more "generic" (or specific) if needed.

Give that a try, and see what you come up with .. ;)

Good luck

Comment: Ran a macro doing what I wanted to do found what I'm looking for is ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1.